# ionic +number format trouble based on the thousand separator

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a problem, which seems to come from the thousand separator.

My html is like this:

```
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Seitenl&auml;nge a (mm):</span>
    <input type="number" placeholder="0" ng-model="cpc.seitenlaengea" ng-change="cpc.refreshCalculation()">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Seitenl&auml;nge b (mm):</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="0" ng-value="cpc.seitenlaengeb | number:10" disabled>
  </label>
```

When the calculation is done, and the value goes over 1000, I get the following warning, and no value is shown:

---

The specified value `"1,028.7037037037"` is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: `-?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?`

---

If I change the type from number to text, then the value is shown like this: `1,028.7037037037`

If I check the value over a console.log, I get something like this: `1028.7037037037037`

So, I think the problem is coming from the thousand separator, and I don't know where the system is getting the number format from!?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand, but I have to give up.

Fact is, that in the API Reference https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number they say it very clear: "Formats a number as text.".

I don't undersand why this is done. I didn't want to make a text out of my number, I just wanted some formatting (rounding).